# Refresh partial locally in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, user-interface, refresh

I have a partial and a separate selection box.

I want to be able to reload the partial with different hash values every time the selection is changed.

I know there is no such entity 'partial' in the client, but is there an easy way to 
refresh the rendered html in the client?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you need to do is make a partial for each selection option. So, if your select options are 'foo', 'bar' , and 'foobar' you would have three partials: `_foo.html.erb`, `_bar.html.erb`, and `_foobar.html.erb`. Then, you can define a helper (let's say `render_selected_partial(option)` where `(option)` takes in what the user selects. You can define the helper as follows:

```
def render_selected_partial(object)
  render: 'views/directory/#{object.attribute}'
end
```

This is very abstract since you haven't provided any concrete examples, and it is assuming that your select box options are types of a defined attribute of the model. I'm not sure what you mean by 'refresh the rendered html in the client' but that seems like an AJAX call that can be triggered when the user makes a selection, and then you can call the helper I defined in the .js file. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution for the server, I ended creating all partials in the server while toggling their visibility as needed

Comment: I'm glad it helps! I now see that you were distinguishing client solution vs. server solution and didn't catch that. But, I've used the solution I presented here and I think it's fairly clean and concise.